# visual basic find database total

Tags: sql, visual-studio, linq

I'm working on creating a visual basic program that can find the sum total of a column from a database file and display it in a label control, and have been stuck for a while. I was hoping that someone could help me out a little.

I've tried a few different ways to accomplish it and they each keep throwing out the same error.

```
  Dim SumQuery = From popualtion In PopulationDBDataSet.City
                       Aggregate order In PopulationDBDataSet.City
                           Into Sum(PopulationDBDataSet.City.PopulationColumn)

  lblTotalPop.Text = SumQuery.ToString
```

and

```
   Dim SumQuery = Aggregate Populaton In PopulationDBDataSet.City
    Into Sumorders = Sum(PopulationDBDataSet.City.PopulationColumn)

    lblAvgPop.Text = SumQuery.ToString
```

Both attempts produce the error "method sum not accessible in this context". Sorry for this post being a bit long but I'm out of ideas on this.

Answer (score 1):

Your usage should include the variable used in Aggregate function:

Try this:

```
Dim SumQuery = From popualtion In PopulationDBDataSet.City
               Aggregate order In PopulationDBDataSet.City
               Into Sum(order.PopulationColumn)
```